# login form needs to go to more form pages

Tags: c#

hi i have a login system that needs to go to multiple pages.
3 pages baroverzicht,keukenoverzicht,tafeloverzicht. if i login i go to tafeloverzicht with all users. i dont know how to fix it i just start coding

SQL server i have a table: **Personeel**

> *naam:*----
>
> *password:*----
>
> *afdelling:* bar, keuken, bediening
>
> bar needs to go to baroverzicht keuken needs to go to keukenoverzicht
>   bediening needs to go to tafeloverzicht

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["ReserveringenConnectionStringSQL"]
                .ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            //----
            //sql datbase connectie
            //----

            conn.Open();        
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from personeel where wachtwoord =" + textBox1.Text + "", conn);
             tabel personeel(wachtwoord) op de vragen
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                count += 1;
            }

            if (count ==1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
                this.Hide();
                tafeloverzicht tafeloverzicht = new tafeloverzicht();
                tafeloverzicht.Show();
            }
           else if (count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wachtwoord niet corect");
            }

            textBox1.Clear();

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is off-topic but it might be interesting to use English throughout your naming convention at all times.
It might throw off some people who don't know Dutch.

Comment: What defines the destination? You state "bar needs to go to baroverzicht keuken needs to go to keukenoverzicht bediening needs to go to tafeloverzicht" but I don't see any value like a "User location" or anything similar that would determine the window to show.

Answer (score 0):

Next to your question there are some other things to take into account:

a. Always use Parameters when creating Sql:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from personeel where wachtwoord = @Password", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", password)
```

b. Put your database methods in a separate class (Encapsulation, etc.) --> example: ReserverationsDataAccess

c. To answer your main question we'll need some more info (see comments).

Answer (score 0):

i have made some changes to the code now.

```
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from personeel where wachtwoord =" + textBox1.Text + "", conn);
       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;
        while(dr.Read())
        {
           count += 1;
        }
        if (count ==1)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select afdeling from personeel where wachtwoord =" + textBox1.Text + "", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("OK");
            if (dr1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "keuken")
            {
                this.Hide();
                keukenoverzicht keukenoverzicht = new keukenoverzicht();
                keukenoverzicht.Show();
            }
            else if (dr1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "bar")
            {
                this.Hide();
                baroverzicht baroverzicht = new baroverzicht();
                baroverzicht.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Hide();
                tafeloverzicht tafeloverzicht = new tafeloverzicht();
                tafeloverzicht.Show();
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("wachtwoord niet corect");
        }

        textBox1.Clear();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

it have now 2 errors on dr1.rows

-a-
what needs to be changed to fix the error (rows)

-b-
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", password) is for ****** in the textbox ride?

[error rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/repEU.png)

Comment: Datareader doesn't have a rows.. Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2.  Specifically, the block that has "while (reader.Read())"